# Comparando registros de três colunas em uma tabela mysql

Tags: mysql, query

Eu faço uma consulta na COL1 que tem o total de linhas e depois faço uma consulta na COL2, porém ela é menor que a COL1. Como faço pra que a COL2 me retorne os IDs iguais aos da COL1 para que elas fiquem lado a lado de acordo com o ID da COL1 para eu ver quem é igual e quem é diferente. Tenho que preencher com zeros a COL2 empurrando os IDs para baixo para igualar os IDs?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: são na mesma tabela ou 3 tabelas diferentes?

Comment: é a mesma table amigo. tenho que comparar os valores das três colunas, então tenho que juntar as três lado a lado, ou seja, adicionar um 0 ou outra coisa nos registros que não tiverem nas outras duas colunas para que elas possam ficar com o mesmo número de linhas.

Comment: Por favor coloque o que você já tem no momento.

Comment: Olá Rogério, a tabela é grande de mais pra colocar aqui. Coloquei uma pequena parte dela.